# Calculation in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to make a simple calculation within aggregation in mongodb?

```
db.xy.aggregate(
{ $match: {"$prc": {$gt : 95/100}}},
{ $group: { _id: {ttl: "$ttl", prg : "$prg"}, sth: {$sum: "$tid"}}},
{ $sort:{ sth: -1 }}
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, just like your `95/100` above, which will get calculated... see the following similar console output

finding documents with sales greater than than 80 (using an unnecessary calculation to illustrate the point - that the second term will be calculated)

```
> db.mat.aggregate({ $match : { "sales" : { $gt : 800 / 10 }}})

{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("503b58387242f5878fa6577f"),
                    "brand" : "Alpha",
                    "sales" : 100,
                    "period" : "2012-01-01"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("503b58497242f5878fa65780"),
                    "brand" : "Alpha",
                    "sales" : 90,
                    "period" : "2012-02-01"
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Applying calculation to a return value, using $project and $divide in the aggregation framework...

```
> db.mat.aggregate({ $project : { "sales_percentage" : { $divide : ["$sales", 100]}}})

{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("503b58387242f5878fa6577f"),
                    "sales_percentage" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("503b58497242f5878fa65780"),
                    "sales_percentage" : 0.9
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("503b58557242f5878fa65781"),
                    "sales_percentage" : 0.8
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Here is a full example that you can save to a file and run via the command line like `C:\MongoDb\mongo < test.js` to see that you can express decimals as 0.x or xx/100 and both work.

```
use example;

db.testData.insert({ name : "test row 1", prc : 0.5 });
db.testData.insert({ name : "test row 2", prc : 0.6 });
db.testData.insert({ name : "test row 3", prc : 0.7 });
db.testData.insert({ name : "test row 4", prc : 0.8 });
db.testData.insert({ name : "test row 5", prc : 0.9 });
db.testData.insert({ name : "test row 6", prc : 1.0 });

print("Using 0.6...");

printjson(
    db.testData.aggregate({ $match : { "prc" : { $gt : 0.6 } } })
);

print("Using 60/100...");

printjson(
    db.testData.aggregate({ $match : { "prc" : { $gt : 60 / 100 } } })
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but do you have any idea why I don't get any result. There are many in the collection...

Comment: Do you get results if you simplify your aggregation and don't group/sort/divide. ie. just  `db.xy.aggregate(
{ $match: { "$prc": { $gt : 0.95 } } })`

Comment: no, that is the reason I tried with division... I get an error.

Incorrect syntax in pipeline
Invalid JSON number '95/100}}}] }'...

With { $match: {"$prc": {$gt : 0.95}}} I just don't get any document 

I get results with ordinary find db.xy.find({ "prc" : { "$gt" : 0.95 } })

Comment: Sorry, correction can you try with `db.xy.aggregate( { $match: { "prc": { $gt : 0.95 } } } )` . ie. no `$` on prc

Comment: @Katja I put in an edit to the answer that gives you some code that you can run on a mongodb to show that this is possible.  Since its really a JavaScript object literal, the same rules apply and so calculation in the expression you're assigning to a property is perfectly acceptable.  Good luck

Comment: It works fine! I was using mongoVUE and as it look there is a bug in aggregation in version 1.6.1. From cmd everything works fine but in MongoVUE i get an error "Incorrect syntax in pipeline...." Thank you very much for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a number of available arithmetic operations [in documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operator-arithmetic/)